# One of the two brown wires to my shower isolator switch is not live. What has caused this please?

Tags: switches

My electric shower stopped working. The shower power button didn’t turn on the shower. I then checked the isolator switch on the ceiling. Its red light didn’t turn on when the switch was on. I checked the cabling to the switch. Of the[image] two brown wires, one of them was live (the furthest one in the image) but the other wasn’t. What has caused this please?

Comment: are they supposed to be both live?

Comment: Try to create a simple wiring diagram for better understanding and to resolve the problem quickly. Merely showing wiring image won't help indeed.

Comment: I had thought that brown cable always carried electricity into an appliance. But the answer below has taught me otherwise. As for a diagram, it looks like the switch is broken so I'll just get a new one.

Comment: What's an electric shower? That sounds terrifying.

Comment: @Hearth it's 230V 30A (7kW) directly heating water, giving the kind of lukewarm piddle that passes for a shower in the UK. What's terrifying is that newer ones are 40A (10kW), and actually an OK shower, except they are often fitted to the original 30A circuit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what I would expect if the switch was broken.  There will be one brown and one blue going in to the switch, and one brown and one blue going out to the shower.

If the switch is broken, then the brown going out may never go live.

Comment: Oh right, thanks! I had thought that brown cables always carried electricity to an appliance. It looks like a broken switch then.